# Changing password field to text with checkbox with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I toggle a password field to text and password with a checkbox check uncheck?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

is this what you looking for ??

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function changeType()
    {
        document.myform.txt.type=(document.myform.option.value=(document.myform.option.value==1)?'-1':'1')=='1'?'text':'password';
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <form name="myform">
       <input type="text" name="txt" />
       <input type="checkbox" name="option" value='1' onchange="changeType()" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `onChange` event when ticking the checkbox and then toggle the input's type to text/password.

Example:

```
<input type="checkbox"  onchange="tick(this)" />
<input type="input" type="text" id="input" />
<script>
function tick(el) {
 $('#input').attr('type',el.checked ? 'text' : 'password');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

updated: live example [here](http://jsbin.com/opafo3)

changing type with `$('#blahinput').attr('type','othertype')` is not possible in IE, considering IE's only-set-it-once rule for the type attribute of input elements.

you need to remove text input and add password input, vice versa.

```
$(function(){
  $("#show").click(function(){
    if( $("#show:checked").length > 0 ){
      var pswd = $("#txtpassword").val();
      $("#txtpassword").attr("id","txtpassword2");
      $("#txtpassword2").after( $("<input id='txtpassword' type='text'>") );
      $("#txtpassword2").remove();
      $("#txtpassword").val( pswd );
    }
    else{ // vice versa
      var pswd = $("#txtpassword").val();
      $("#txtpassword").attr("id","txtpassword2");
      $("#txtpassword2").after( $("<input id='txtpassword' type='password'>") );
      $("#txtpassword2").remove();
      $("#txtpassword").val( pswd );
    }
  });
})
```

live example [here](http://jsbin.com/opafo3)

Comment: Update: I don't know for the time of the question, but your first code works if you try .prop('type') nowadays.

Comment: @fredlegrain Nope not on IE8

Answer (score 2):

You can use some thing like this

```
$("#showHide").click(function () {
                if ($(".password").attr("type")=="password") {
                    $(".password").attr("type", "text");
                }
                else{
                    $(".password").attr("type", "password");
                }

    });
```

visit here for more http://voidtricks.com/password-show-hide-checkbox-click/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can call

```
$('#inputField').attr('type','text');
```

and

```
$('#inputField').attr('type','password');
```

depending on the checkbox state.

Comment: not possible in IE, considering IE's only-set-it-once rule for the type attribute of input elements. not a jQuery bug

Answer (score 0):

I have the following in production.  It clones a new field having the toggled type.

```
toggle_clear_password = function( fields ) {

  // handles a list of fields, or just one of course
  fields.each(function(){
    var orig_field = $(this);
    var new_field =  $(document.createElement('input')).attr({
      name:  orig_field.attr('name'),
      id:    orig_field.attr('id'),
      value: orig_field.val(),
      type:  (orig_field.attr('type') == 'text'? 'password' : 'text')
    })
    new_field.copyEvents(orig_field); // jquery 'copyEvents' plugin
    orig_field.removeAttr('name'); // name clashes on a form cause funky submit-behaviour
    orig_field.before(new_field);
    orig_field.remove();
  });
}
```

JQuery doesn't just let you take the type attribute and change it, at least not the last time I tried.

Answer (score 0):

Toggle the checkbox's focus event and determain the checkbox's status and update the field as nesscarry

```
$box = $('input[name=checkboxName]');

    $box.focus(function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('input[name=PasswordInput]').attr('type', 'password');    
        } else {
            $('input[name=PasswordInput]').attr('type', 'text');
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    $(function(){
       $("#changePass").click(function(){
          if ($("#txttext").hasClass("hide")){
              $("#txttext").val( $("#txtpass").val() ).removeClass("hide");
              $("#txtpass").addClass("hide");
          } else if ($("#txtpass").hasClass("hide")){
              $("#txtpass").val( $("#txttext").val() ).removeClass("hide");
              $("#txttext").addClass("hide");
          }
       });
    });
</script>
<style>
  .hide{display:none;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="myform">
       <input type="text" id="txtpass" type='password'/>
       <input class="hide" type="text" id="txttext" type='text'/>
       <button id="changePass">change</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

oncheck

```
$('#password').get(0).type = 'text';
```

onuncheck

```
$('#password').get(0).type = 'password';
```

Answer (score 0):

.attr('type') was blocked by jQuery team because it won't work with some versions of IE.

Consider using this code :

```
$('#inputField').prop('type','text');
$('#inputField').prop('type','password');
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be implemented much simpler:

```
<form name="myform">
   <input type="password" name="password" />
   <input type="checkbox" name="showPassword" onchange="togglePasswordVisibility()" />
</form>

<script>
    function togglePasswordVisibility() {
        $('#password').attr('type',  $('#showPassword').prop('checked') ? 'text' : 'password');
    }
</script>
```

Works for jQuery 1.6+