# Why isn't this code jquery working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [changing password field to text with checkbox with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970793/changing-password-field-to-text-with-checkbox-with-jquery)

The code is supposed to check if a checkbox is checked, then change a password field from password to regular text and vice versa.

```
$('#cpassword_lf').change(function(){
     if($('#cpassword_lf').is(':checked'))
     {
        $('#password_loginform').attr('type', 'text'); 
     }
     else
     {
         $('#password_loginform').attr('type', 'password'); 
     }  
 });
```

Comment: Need more info! Browser, errors, etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't allowed to change the type attribute, here is a simple solution to do the same thing though: http://jsfiddle.net/ryWgY/2

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cpassword_lf" />
<input type="password" id="password_loginform_hidden" />
<input type="text" id="password_loginform_clear" />
```

Javascript:

```
$(function ()
{
    $('#password_loginform_clear').hide();
    $('#cpassword_lf').change(function()
    {
         if(!$('#cpassword_lf').is(':checked'))
         {
             $('#password_loginform_clear').hide();
             $('#password_loginform_hidden').show();

             $('#password_loginform_hidden').val($('#password_loginform_clear').val());
             $('#password_loginform_clear').val('');
         }
         else
         {
             $('#password_loginform_clear').show();
             $('#password_loginform_hidden').hide();

             $('#password_loginform_clear').val($('#password_loginform_hidden').val());
             $('#password_loginform_hidden').val('');
         }  
    });
});
```

Comment: Edited to include the code, thanks for reminding.  Wish SO had a similar solution to jsfiddle (it's so nice!)

Answer (score 2):

From the jQuery documentation on [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2):

> jQuery prohibits changing the type attribute on an  or 
>   element and will throw an error in all browsers. This is because the
>   type attribute cannot be changed in Internet Explorer.

See linked questions for various solutions to this problem.

As a side note, inside the event handler `this` will refer to the element that has changed, so you don't need to use a selector again:

```
$("#someElem").change(function() {
    //$(this) == $("#someElem")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, browsers typically won't allow you to change the type of an input. Here are some suggested solutions:

[jQuery: Change element type from hidden to input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540851/jquery-change-element-type-from-hidden-to-input)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.attr` try using `.prop`

```
$('#cpassword_lf').change(function(){
   if($(this).is(':checked'))
      $('#password_loginform').prop('type', 'text');
   else
      $('#password_loginform').prop('type', 'password');    
});
```

Not sure what the downvote was about: http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/qMhug/
Seems to work in Chrome, FF, and Safari (can't test in IE atm)

Comment: Does not solve the issue (see other answers) and should be noted that using `attr` in place of `prop` is only an issue in jQuery 1.6 and up.

Comment: I don't know, works for me in Safari and Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/qMhug/

Comment: As per answer by James, it's really an Explorer issue.

Comment: Well he was right about this, but attr and prop are not the same - I don't get an error in every browser - could you test IE for me?

Comment: In IE 8, I get a jQuery error, _"Could not get the type property. This command is not supported."_

Comment: Are you sure? I tried it in IE9 or 10 and it worked.

Comment: I'm 100% positive.  IE 8 in XP... the error I posted was a cut & paste from your jsFiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/qMhug/

Comment: ahh i confirmed IE9 Win7 is good, but that makes sense since MS made all though compliancy improvements

Answer (score -1):

As others have stated: this is pretty much a duplicate of [jQuery: Change element type from hidden to input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540851/jquery-change-element-type-from-hidden-to-input).

Applying the answer to that question to your specific case, you end up with this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $('#cpassword_lf').change(function(){
    var pass_or_text_input = $('#password_loginform');
    var marker = $('<span />').insertBefore(pass_or_text_input);
    pass_or_text_input.detach();
    if ($('#cpassword_lf').is(':checked')) {
      pass_or_text_input.attr('type', 'text'); 
    } else {
      pass_or_text_input.attr('type', 'password'); 
    }
    pass_or_text_input.insertAfter(marker);
    marker.remove();
  });
});
</script>
<input id="cpassword_lf" type="checkbox"></input>
<input id="password_loginform" value="secret"></input>
```

Comment: As others have already stated, jQuery will not allow you to change the `type` attribute because of issues with Explorer.

Comment: @Sparky672: This snippet doesn't work in IE9, but it works in FF and Chrome, so I figured it worth mentioning.

Comment: Welcome to SO... where not everything is worth mentioning (as an answer).